# Index of the first cell in jagged array in C#

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

What is the index of the first cell (the first left cell in first line and first row) in jagged array in C#?

```
a[0][0]?? 
a[0][1]??
```

Comment: A simple breakpoint followed by hovering over the array (once the breakpoint hit) with your mouse would tell you that.

Comment: the index starts from zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is defined as `int[][]`, then the first line would be `a[0]`, and the first cell `a[0][0]`. I should suggest that you try to find out such simple things by experiment.